# WT8266-S1 WiFi module

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi

WT8266-S1 WiFi module in my hand I want to encode this module with Ardino IDE. I have a coded program for Arduino NodeMCU 1.0. How can I convert it to the WT8266-S1 WiFi module? Do you have the WT8266-S1 WiFi module source code? Firebase connection to do the application to turn off the LED. Below is a sample code share.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp01(9,11); 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp01.begin(9600); 

  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);   
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);

  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);

  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000); 
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000); 
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000); 
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000); 
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000); 
}

void loop()
{
  if(esp01.available()) 
  {
    if(esp01.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(1000); 

     // odczytanie ID połączenia
     int connectionId = esp01.read()-48; 

     esp01.find("pin="); 

     int pinNumber = (esp01.read()-48)*10; 
     pinNumber += (esp01.read()-48); 
     digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); 
      String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; 
     closeCommand+="\r\n";

     sendData(closeCommand,1000); 
    }
  }
}

String sendData(String command, const int timeout)
{
    String response = "";

    esp01.print(command); 

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp01.available()) 
      {
        char c = esp01.read(); 
        response += c;
      }  
    } 
    Serial.print(response);
    return response;
}
```

Warning: espcomm_sync failed when I install this thread
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
 getting the error

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I shared a sample code on the subject.

Comment: this a sketch for an MCU with external esp8266 module with AT firmware  wired to Serial interface. you try to upload it to the esp8266?

Comment: Is it possible that I want to load code into module WT8266? I wrote code for NodeMCU 1.0 and I want to edit it for the wt8266 module. @Juraj

Comment: Can I write code for wt8266 as same as esp8266? Is this possible? @Juraj

Comment: don't know. but sure is, you can't use the esp8266 AT firmware 'from inside'. because if you upload your sketch, it replaces the AT firmware as the application running on the esp8266. how did you wire the WT8266 and do you put it into flashing mode before upload?

Comment: I understood thank you. Connected to computer with USB TTL cable. Yes is currently running in flashing mode. @Juraj

Comment: has it AT firmware? can you execute AT command on in from computer? for example from Serial Monitor of the Arduino IDE?